# Changing meta name for theme via Tumblr API

Tags: html, tumblr

I was wondering if it is possible to change a meta name variable in my Tumblr theme's HTML through Tumblr's API in any way?

Basically, I have following variable, which I use to set the color of all my links in my Tumblr theme.

```
<meta name="color:mycolor" content="#000000"/>
```

I then have a list of random colors that I parsed from another website and put into a text file with Python.

Is there any way I can select a line of text from the file or somehow use Python to replace the `content` variable?

It doesn't necessarily need to be read from the text file.

Comment: Sadly not. The only way to modify a `meta` tag is to use theme variables as these are rendered server side. However they lack any logic to make something random. You could use `javascript` client side to alter the `css` and add your random colour.

Comment: I reworded the title